aggrregated vs. non aggregated data
I am running a TWFE logistic regression to regress a company's exit status, meaning 1 if the invested company had an IPO and 0 if not. I am running the following code specification:
logit_model_exit <- feglm(dv_success ~ ddd | firm_name + 
    investment_date, data=data2, family = binomial(link = "logit"))

I have an unbalanced panel dataset with about 150 companies (75 treatment and 75 control, matched through coarsened exact matching) for 23 years. The original dataset contains all deals these companies (venture capital firms) were involved in as well as their characteristics. I have aggregated some of the data and created a compiled dataset with each VC company in each year and the corresponding aggregated numbers such as the exit rate of their investments.
I ran the TWFE logit with both the aggregated and the deal level data. I am not sure why the estimates I get are so different, and why when using the aggregated data the estimate is significant while when using the original data the estimator is not significant at all. My deal-level data contains 63k observations and my aggregate data around 2300.
estimator.  std error.   z value.   Pr(>|z|)
0.24363     0.128339    -1.8983.    0.057653.    -> for aggregated data
-0.071454   0.083729    -0.853397   0.39344      -> for deal level data

Any idea on how to make sense of this?

What does the ddd variable represent?

@DoctorMilt it's a dummy indicating whether the company has received treatment in that specific year. firm_name and investment_date (which is the year) are entitiy and time fixed effects. I have also added control variables but did not include them for better overview.

Thank you. And just to be clear: in the aggregated model, you still model the number of successes, but with the number of trials set equal to the number of deals you are aggregating. Is this correct?

Did the direction of this effect reverse after aggregating? I’m looking at the $z$ values and was curious.
